# Cython: How to pass binary string(with internal null bytes) to external C function

Tags: python-2.7, cython

```
void a_c_function(unsigned char* str, uint32_t str_length);

python_str = ... # a python binary string with internal null bytes
```

The payload of the data is `python_str[head_length:]`.

Question> How could I pass this payload data to `a_c_function`?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problem? Cython can automatically convert Python strings to `char*` and the string length is trivial to get.

Comment: will I run into the problem of the string with null bytes in the middle of the string?

Comment: No - the automatic conversion to `char*` doesn't make a copy - it just returns a pointer to the data that already exists